# UIScrollView Not scrolling in iOS11

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint, ios11

I have created a `UIScrollView` in code and it works in iOS10.  I updated my Xcode today and it is no longer scrolling in iOS11 (simulator is iOS11 and does not work; physical iPad is still iOS10 and works).

User can add subviews when they want.  When its the first subview, I anchor it to the left side, top and bottom of the scroll view.  Then I anchor the right side of the subview to the right side of the scroll view which gives the `contentSize` its size and so it knows it needs to enable scrolling

```
UIScrollView *scrollViewMain = [UIScrollView new];
scrollViewMain.delegate = self;
scrollViewMain.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
scrollViewMain.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
scrollViewMain.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
self.scrollViewMain = scrollViewMain;

... // other code

if (self.countPlayers == 1) {
    [self.scrollViewMain addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[playerCardView(400)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(playerCardView)]];
    [self.scrollViewMain addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[playerCardView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(playerCardView)]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollViewMain attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:playerCardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:10];

    self.constraintScrollViewRight = constraint;

    [self.scrollViewMain addConstraint:constraint];
}
else {
    [self.scrollViewMain addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[previousPlayerCardView]-[playerCardView(==previousPlayerCardView)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"previousPlayerCardView": player.previousPlayer.playerViewCard, @"playerCardView": player.playerViewCard}]];

    [self.scrollViewMain addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[playerCardView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(playerCardView)]];
}

if (self.constraintScrollViewRight) {
    [self.scrollViewMain removeConstraint:self.constraintScrollViewRight];
}

NSLayoutConstraint *constraintRight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollViewMain attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:playerCardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:10];
self.constraintScrollViewRight = constraintRight;
[self.scrollViewMain addConstraint:constraintRight];

[self.scrollViewMain layoutIfNeeded];
DLog(@"self.scrollViewMain: %@", self.scrollViewMain);
DLog(@"self.scrollViewMain.contentSize: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollViewMain.contentSize));
```

The `contentSize` does become larger then the scroll view's frame:

```
2017-10-04 20:01:58.479446-0500 [ViewController addPlayer]_block_invoke [Line 242] self.scrollViewMain: <UIScrollView: 0x7fa9fd01b000; frame = (286 20; 462 1014); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000005ff20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000233580>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {826, 89}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
2017-10-04 20:01:58.479969-0500 [ViewController addPlayer]_block_invoke [Line 243] self.scrollViewMain.contentSize: {826, 89}
```

Why does iOS11 break my code?

EDIT:

Also, I try to scroll to the right to show the new subview when it appears:

```
    [self.scrollViewMain scrollRectToVisible:playerCardView.frame animated:YES];
```

And it does nothing.

SOLUTION:

I changed

```
[self.scrollViewMain addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[playerCardView(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(playerCardView)]];
```

To

```
[self.scrollViewMain addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollViewMain attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:playerCardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:10]];
```

The `UIScrollView` now has a left and right anchor and can calculate its `contentSize`.

Kind of a crappy bug that the Visual Format is partially broken now.

Comment: Has anyone filed a bug with Apple on this yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating all your constraints without using *NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:*

I've just had the exact same problem in my app on iOS 11, after upgrading to XCode 9.

After several hours of trying to find out what constraint caused the problems in my code, I happened to replace all calls to *NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:* with building the constraints "by code" using *NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:* instead; and now it works as it's supposed to...

I guess Apple has modified the visual format analyzer in a way that causes some unexpected side effects...

Comment: This is a significant refactor... has anyone else had the same success as @Hypo? Also @Hypo, did you refactor *all* your constraints or just the subviews of the UIScrollView?

Comment: Just the immediate subviews of UIScrollView... My guess is that it is only the constraints that connect to the content width and/or height of the UIScrollView that beeds to be refactored... At least that what it seems like in my case...

Comment: This did it.  I changed the VF to a constraint and it scrolls now.  Added solution.  I'm guessing it only has to do with `UIScrollView`; subviews need to be attached to the side of a scroll view so it can calculate the `contentSize` and know if it needs to scroll.

Answer (score 6):

> Why does iOS11 break my code?

Because that is Apple's job.

Comment: Haha, that was a quick response!

Comment: :D It is true man. Everytime a new iOS comes out, something breaks. Hope there is a practical solution to this one. Meanwhile, sorry for abusing the answer section. having same problem here.

Comment: Same problem as well. I also have somehow a "infinite loop" calculating the `content size` that brings my app to freeze when adding layout constraints. 
Still same issue on iOS 11.1 beta. :(